# Can an interpretation be given to arbitrary infinite sums of sines, as encountered in path integrals in QFT?

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-series, distribution-theory

While computing matrix elements of the evolution operator in Quantum Field Theory for the harmonic oscillator using the path integral formalism, I came across the assumption that all physically relevant paths are functions of a particular type, which I found puzzling. Therefore I would like to understand better what type of paths I am dealing with here. To be precise, let $t_1< t_2$ and $q_1,q_2$ be real numbers, then all paths of the following type are considered physical: paths given by functions (possibly by lack of a better word)
$$
q(t) = f(t) + g(t),
$$
where $f$ is a smooth real function obeying $f(t_1) = q_1$ and $f(t_2) = q_2$ and $g$ is of the form
$$
g(t) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k \sin\left(\pi k \frac{t-t_1}{t_2-t_1}\right).
$$
The functions $\sin\left(\pi k \frac{t-t_1}{t_2-t_1}\right)$ form an orthonormal basis of 
$$
L^2_0=\left\{g\in L^2\left([t_1,t_2]\right)| g(t_1) = g(t_2) = 0\right\},
$$
but it seems obvious that not every set of coefficients $a_k$ will define a function $g\in L^2_0$: by choosing a strongly divergent series for the $a_k$ we will definitely create a series that does not converge for almost all $t$.

My question now is: what can we possibly say about the objects that are defined by this series when the $a_k$ are arbitrary real numbers? In other words, characterize the set given by
$$
\left\{g(t) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k \sin\left(\pi k \frac{t-t_1}{t_2-t_1}\right) | a_i \in \mathbb{R} \mbox{ for all } i \right\}.
$$
I understand that this series does not converge for all possible sequences $a_k$: it might however in those cases be possible to interpret it as the formal series of some other object, such as a distribution. I am also interested in such interpretations.

I cannot say much more than that this set definitely encompasses $L^2_0\left([t_1,t_2]\right)$ but is most definitely bigger.

Comment: The first question would be: How do you even define the limit if there are no growth assumptions on $(a_k)$?

Comment: @MaoWao I am open to different definitions: the series might also be interpreted as the formal series of some other object, such as a distribution, for which the series does not need to have a limit.

Comment: does your definition of this set implicitly entail that the series converges for every $t \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ or is the function $g$ allowed to have $\infty$ as a value?

Comment: @user159517 I have addressed your comment more thoroughly in the question. Note however that I am looking for a characterization of the set that is as precise as possible. For me, saying that some of the $g$ in the set have $\infty$ as a value is not very precise.

Comment: I should remark that the functions are an orthogonal system in $L^2([t_1,t_2])$ but not a basis, if you want a basis you must include $\cos$ terms also.

Comment: @s.harp thanks, that is right. I updated the question accordingly